# Hi. how to play 2 audio files in html5?

Tags: html, audio

this my code

```
<audio preload='false' id='player'>
            <source src='https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/mp3/player.wav?w=7e152d8e' />
        </audio>
        <audio preload='false' id='ai'>
            <source 'https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/mp3/ai.wav?w=431eb010'/>
        </audio>
```

js

```
playerWav = document.getElementById('player', false);
    aiWav = document.getElementById('ai');
```

...

```
    if(contact_player(ball, player)){
        playerWav.play();
```

...

```
if(contact_ai(ball, ai)){
            playerWav.play();
```

playerWav.play() dont play( need help plees

Comment: Your second source tag doesn't include the src attribute. Could that be one of the problems?

Comment: Just a warning - iOS doesn't support multiple audio streams at once, and even if you have two that aren't playing at the same time, you still have to be really careful. See http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW10

Answer (score 1):

`wav` files are not officially supported by HTML5 players and have no compression and therefore obscene bitrates.  Use an officially supported format.

Comment: According to the W3Schools HTML5 audio reference (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp), wav is supported by all common, recent browsers except IE.

Comment: I stand corrected.  And also Opera doesn't support it.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html5_audio#Audio_format_support

*but* it's still a horrible, horrible idea.

Comment: i change to mp3, all the same playerWav.play() dont play

Comment: And you've omitted the `type` attribute also.  Why don't you use the resource you referenced?

Answer (score 0):

A summary of a few possible problems:

1. There is no `src=` in the second source tag.
2. There is no type specified in either source tag. (Try `type="audio/wav"`.)
3. The links to the audio files are broken, although that may be because they are links to your private Dropbox and require you to login.